# Beam triggers: emit every X events, and emit finally at the end of the Window only if non-empty

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We are building a Beam pipeline that processes stream data, the destination of which writes data to the database after some transformations.

Due to the tradeoff between latency and efficiency of the use of database connections, we decided on this behavior:

1. Use a window of 5 seconds, taking into account late records by 1 sec
2. In periods of high-throughput (high-volume of data being streamed), trigger repeatedly WITHIN the window for each 500 records
3. Events emitted earlier than the end of the window, says the 500 records, should be its own group or batch being written to the database
4. Finally, emit at the end of the window, including late data, ONLY IF non-empty (do not fire if zero events). Ideally, but optional, late records should be grouped in a final pane, rather than the Window emitting event for each late record.
5. If there are no event within the window, never emit anything.

```
# listen to Pubsub subscription containing Cloud Storage location
# get file from Cloud Storage
gcs_filepaths = pipeline | "Read Pubsub" >> ...
                         | "Get GCS Filepath" >> ...

# read the avro files into, each record becoming events
records = gcs_filepaths  | "Read Avro" >> avroio.ReadAllFromAvro()
 
transforms = records     | "Transform Data" >> beam.ParDo(TransformDoFn())

# previous step yields: (table_name::str, row_data::dict)
windows = transforms     | "Window" >> beam.WindowInto(
                            window.FixedWindows(5),
                            trigger=trigger.Repeatedly(
                                trigger.AfterAny(
                                    trigger.AfterCount(500), 
                                    trigger.AfterProcessingTime(5))
                            ),
                      accumulation_mode=trigger.AccumulationMode.DISCARDING,
                            allowed_lateness=1
                        )
                        
grouping = windows | "Grouping Per Window" >> beam.GroupByKey()

grouping | "Write To DB" >> beam.ParDo(WriteDataToDBDoFn(...))
```

Is the code above correct?

However, we have observed that the PTransform "Grouping Per Window" groups all events as one, essentially batching the records of the whole window in a single database write. How do I make each early 500 events grouped into its own pane and proceed to be written to the DB even without the window finishing?

In addition, the window still fires a final event with 0 records. How do we specify in Python not to fire if no records?

I've seen somewhere that in Java this is possible:

```
.withAllowedLateness(allowedLateness, Window.ClosingBehavior.FIRE_IF_NON_EMPTY)
```

I wonder what is the equivalent in Python.